# Python how to split a string inside a list

Tags: python, string, list, split

This is my current code:

```
def poisci_pare(besedilo):
    import re
    seznam = re.split("[.]", besedilo)
    return seznam
```

this returns (we assume the sentences will always end with a dot `.`)

```
poisci_pare("Hello world. This is great.")
>>>output: ["Hello world", "This is great"]
```

What would I have to write to get python to split the string like this:

```
poisci_pare("Hello world. This is great.")
>>>output: [["Hello", "world"], ["This", "is", "great"]]
```

Comment: Im actually suprised that worked ... `.` typically means any character in regex ... I guess when its in a box bracket it treats it as a literal ...

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it would work in the first place, but after some experimenting with re.split I got it to work perfectly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def poisci_pare(text):
    sents = text.split('.')
    answer = [sent.split() for sent in sents if sent]
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [8]: poisci_pare("Hello world. This is great.")
Out[8]: [['Hello', 'world'], ['This', 'is', 'great']]
```

Answer (score 0):

this also will do the trick:

```
input = "Hello world. This is great."
print [s.split() for s in input.split('.') if s.split()]
[['Hello', 'world'], ['This', 'is', 'great']]
```